Website remembers personal details that I entered
So I am currently working on the react js project but there is an 'error' that I encounter every time, I try to sign in or sign up to test functionality then when I try to open a new account local website(maybe Chrome) remembers other details and offer for me such as auto-complete. But I don't wanna see them. I deleted all of them but still they appear when I try the same process. How to remove them or this feature(if it is a feature)?


You can try setting the "autocomplete" tag to "off". Here is an example:
<input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off">

Or
<form autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
</form>

Do let me know if it works.

this might be because of autocomplete is on in the form you can turn it off by


<input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off" />



